# how to get user latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift4, core-location

I am trying to get a user's latitude and longitude values, but the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s methods are not getting called. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationmanager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationmanager.delegate = self;
        locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationmanager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //MARK: - location delegate methods
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }
}
```

Comment: are you get the alert prompt initially

Comment: Have you added  `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription ` in info.plist ?

Comment: And check granted access for your application in a iPhone settings. Your application should have access to the location services.

Comment: I have added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and i am getting that alert also.but i am not getting latitude and longitude values, and i am running my app in simulator

Comment: Please test it on device code is perfect. and make sure iPhone device location privacy will turn on. and for simulator test please follow this step go to top bar and select debug -> locations -> apple. then run your project it will work.

Comment: it's working for you, are you able to get the current location. @Swathi

Answer (score 1):

You can typically okay. To access user's current location you need physical device.

Still, there are second way to simulate location on simulator using **Simulate Location** option available above console in toolbar. This option available when your application is running.

Click on it to see list of location and select location to get device location on simulator. It's will be not current location but **Simulate Location** will set simulator location to your selected location. See following image:

[image: Simulate Location]

You can also add your custom GPX file to load your current location. You can also add your Customer Location from debug menu of simulator. See following image:

[image: Customer Location]

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**import following framework**

```
Import CoreLocation
```

if you want Display map

```
Import MapKit
```

You can determine user’s current location by declaring
 CLLocationManager instance:

`let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`

In `viewDidLoad()` you have to instantiate the `CLLocationManager` class,
 like so:

```
// Ask for Authorisation from the User.
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 
// For use in foreground
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Then in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method you can get user's current
 location coordinates:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

In the info.plist you will have to add
Make sure you set following privacy permission.
 Also, make sure simulator’s location service is ON.

- Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Comment: Import MapKit if user want to display map

Comment: I an getting that custom alert but i am not able to get lat,long values

Comment: Are you testing on Real Device ?

Comment: If you are running in the simulator hen you need to use the debug menu to simulate a location.

Comment: please check on device also you will get desire result .